# Problem using jQueryWTP 0.36 for Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

I am trying to get jQueryWTP to work with Elipse 3.5.2.  I followed the instructions and the new jar file was created (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core_1.0.201.v2010012803.jar).  I replaced this new jar file with the old jar file in the Eclipse plugin directory.  However, when I started Eclipse I saw an error with this jar file.

Here is the error I am seeing in the Eclipse log file:
Either the manifest file or the signature file has been tampered in this jar: C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse 3.5.2\plugins\org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core_1.0.201.v2010012803.jar

Has anyone else received this type of error when installing jQueryWTP?  And, if so did you find a workaround to get this to work?

I have spent much time researching this and have not come up with a solution.  I did see that someone else had this problem, but there wasn't a solution provided.

Trish

Answer (score 0):

If you can/want you may be interested in trying out Aptana Studio (http://www.aptana.com/)... It has great support for a lot of js frameworks and intellisense.

HTH

Cheers!